# IMG onclick="LinkModalDialog()" dont work on Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html

i'm using this

```
function LinkModalDialog(obj){

    var arr=showModalDialog("../../files/list_simple.asp","","dialogHeight: 600px; dialogWidth: 450px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; resizable: Yes; status: Yes; scroll: Yes; help: No;");
    if (arr) obj.value=arr; 
    arr=null;
}
```

And when i call it on Mozilla cant work 
I call it like this

```
<IMG onclick="LinkModalDialog(txt_file)" style="cursor : hand;" onMouseOut="MM_displayStatusMsg('');return document.MM_returnValue" onMouseOver="MM_displayStatusMsg('1111111');return document.MM_returnValue" align=top border=0 alt="11111" src="<%=imagesDir%>/uploadbtn.gif">
```

the window not open on mozilla

Comment: <IMG onclick="LinkModalDialog(txt_odigies_pdf6)" style="cursor : hand;" onMouseOut="MM_displayStatusMsg('');return document.MM_returnValue" onMouseOver="MM_displayStatusMsg('1111');return document.MM_returnValue" align=top border=0 alt="1111" src="<%=imagesDir%>/uploadbtn.gif">

Comment: function LinkModalDialog(obj){
 var arr=showModalDialog("../../files/list_simple.asp","","dialogHeight: 600px; dialogWidth: 450px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; resizable: Yes; status: Yes; scroll: Yes; help: No;");
 if (arr) obj.value=arr; 
 arr=null;
}

Comment: You can use the **edit** button to edit your question.

Comment: When you say "Mozilla" (which is a company that makes a number of different software products) do you mean "Firefox"?

Comment: I mean Firefox yes !!! Sorry for not being specific

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN: `Window.showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog):

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.
>
> ---
>
> This feature has been removed. Please fix your Web sites and applications.
>
> This method was removed in Chrome 43, and Firefox 56.